# JS/HTML5 game engine for isometric game, "simcity" like

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-engine, isometric

I need to select a game engine/library to jumpstart a project of "simcity" like game targeted for browsers+facebook. So far i found two engines that look promising (examples don't cause rendering artifacts):

http://www.isogenicengine.com/ (paid)
http://libcanvas.github.com/ (open source beta)

Anyone has any expirence with those or other engines for isometric game (turn based). Or should i reinvent the wheel :)

Thanks in advance!